# How to know if the user is on mobile in css?

Tags: css, mobile

How to know if the user is on mobile in CSS?
I am making a mobile detector, but I don't know how to know the user on mobile. can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you need to make that `p` tag disappear on mobiles and that is fairly simple.
Simply add another media query above the previous one but with a `max-width` of 767px like so:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        p {
            display: none;
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        p {
            display:block;
        }
    }
```

Now, the `p` tag will be invisible in mobile view but visible on screens above 767px.

Comment: However, if you need it to be reversed, i.e for the p tag to show when it's in mobile, just swap the code snippets within each of the media queries for a reverse effect.